# Laravel testing not execute when using trans helper on data provider

Tags: laravel, validation, testing, phpunit, translation

I have problem when testing validating using data provider..
When i use translation helper the test not execute but when use normal text (string) the testing run normal...

But i want use translation helper to easy maintenance in future...

Here my example code :

```
/**
 * @dataProvider validateFirstNameProvider
 */
public function testStoreValidation($attribute, $value, $message)
{
    $response = $this->actingAs($this->user)
        ->post(route('user.store'), [
            $attribute=> $value,
        ]);

    $response->assertSessionHasErrorsIn('validation', [
        $attribute => $message,
    ]);
}

public function validateFirstNameProvider()
{
    return [
        'required first name' => [
            'first_name',
            '',
            trans('validation.required', [
                'attribute' => trans('validation.attributes.first_name'),
            ]),
        ],
    ];
}
```

Code without use translation helper :

```
public function validateFirstNameProvider()
{
    return [
        'required first name' => [
            'first_name',
            '',
            'The first name field is required.',
        ],
    ];
}
```

Comment: I think the `@dataProvider` runs before Laravel is properly bootstrapped so you can't use most of the framework functionality in there. I don't know of any solution to this, but it's something to keep in mind

Comment: You can't access the application instance in the dataProvider, because of the way PHPUnit is working. You can either use the trans in the test method or make your customer dataProvider.

Comment: Ok.. thank u for the explanation...  i will refractor my testing code now